# sending html form data to java application

Tags: java, forms

Is there any possible way to send the html form data to java application without using php and asp stuff?
I know we can do this using php and do it before but can i do it directly?
I had used php in my previous app in which user sends his data to php form that saves it into the data base but now i want to directly get the data from the html form.PLease any idea for that?

Comment: Umm... if you want to send it to a java application, why would you be using PHP at all?  If it's just pure java and it's simple, you could just use a socket: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/.  If it's more complicated, you could look into a java webserver, like Deft.

Comment: if i create my own web server in java,then how i will get the form data?

Comment: I mean what should i write in the action attribute of form tag <form action"">

Comment: @Sharpzain — The URI that your webserver has mapped onto your servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the data by using jsp or by sending it in a link like www.google.com?q=usa
and parse it on other side

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could consider using Java Servlets and JSP for web-based data processing ?

Comment: Java servlet is server side programming?

Comment: Yup, it is a server side for Java.

Answer (score 2):

use the html form action attribute to specify an endpoint that will hit a java servlet running inside of a servlet container.

To handle the request in your java class, implement the HttpServlet interface.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

If you are posting from a form, them most likely you will want to implement doPost.  Or you can implement service as a catch-all

Example:

```
<form action="/path/to/Servlet" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo"/>
</form>
```

....

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respnose) {
    // set String foo to the form element named "foo"
    String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
    // now do whatever you need to w/ foo
}
```

Comment: I had created the webserver itself in java and my webserver doesnt support any server side language like php,asp,xml,servlet.what should i do now?I had seen several servlet programs on internet but they donot have a main() method..

Answer (score 1):

Try Tomcat with Java Servlets.  You need to:

- write a class that extends HttpServlet
- override the "doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)" or "doGet(...)" methods
- write a web.xml file mapping the web page URL to the servlet handling the request
- compile and bundle everything together as required.

It'll take a little doing to get everything in the right place but it's not too hard.  See the Tomcat documentation for further details.  Good luck.